# Содержимое файла .tgz c помощью HTTPBuilder запроса не видно в Artifactory

Tags: rest, groovy, artifactory

я загружаю .tgz файл в jfrog artifactory с помощью обычного curl put запроса, затем захожу через веб интерфейс в браузер артефактов и могу развернуть файл стрелочкой, чтобы посмотреть содержимое. 
но когда тот же самый запрос генерирую HTTPBuilder'ом, файл успешно загружается, но через веб браузер я уже не могу развернуть его и видеть содержимое.

Использую

http.getAuth().basic(artifactoryUsername,artifactoryPassword)
    http.request(Method.PUT,ContentType.JSON)

Подозреваю, что делов в ContentType, но не так много опыта.

Любая помощь приветствуется.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, у вас указан неверный `ContentType`. Я не уверен, какой должен быть в `ContentType` в данном случае, но если при выполнении curl без указания типа, то я бы порекомендовал просто его не указывать при вызове метода.